# ONLY allow HTTPS, HTTP and Postgres Outgoing ports

Tags: ubuntu, security

I have Ubuntu server and I ONLY want to allow outgoing connections to ANY IP to the following:

- HTTPS
- HTTP
- Postgres

I want to block all other ports. And I would like to see connections being made from the ports so I can open the ports in case needed.

How can I set it up on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Have a look at `ufw` (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall)

Comment: Your intention is unclear.  Can you advise if you are looking to only allow requests associated with the outside world coming to your http,https or postgres server, or if these are services you want to access on the wider Internet?    You mention outgoing connections - is the "outgoing" bit important - depending on your answer to the first part of the question this could be relevant.

Comment: Also, you are talking about blocking all other ports.  Did you intend for this to include DNS?

Comment: With respect of connections being made from ports in need, what do you actually mean?  Stuff not on 80,443 or 5432, or something else?

Answer (score -1):

A  rules set for outgoing connections might be :

```
# Allow establishing connections to desired set of services
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 5432 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Log any outgoing connection attempts
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp -p tcp  -j LOG --log-uid --log-prefix="outgoing connection: "    

# Allow incomig traffic for established connections
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# set default policy to drop
sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

Use ip6tables to add IPv6 rules, if necessary.

I assume, you still need to allow ssh access to be able to access the host.

**Be aware: by misconfiguring firewall rules remotely you can lock yourself out! **

Comment: These are inefficient and don't really answer the question.

Comment: davidgo you can add the missing part or write a new answer. Or at least elaborate what is wrong. Other wise, your comment didn't help to answer the question.

Comment: you are right.  Apologies. I was on my mobile and in a grumpy mood.  I also stuffed up so I can't undo my downvote unless you change your answer. I can't answer the question without it being clarified, but your answer makes use of connection tracking - and in such a way that would stop it being logged - which may not be desired and is inefficinet.  Your catch-all output rule logs other new tcp requests, but ignores other traffic, and does not block anything - the default rule might or might not catch this.